# my website crash on safari The site sometimes crashes and I can't recover the crash

Tags: iphone, safari, crash

hello everyone i have an issue with safari/iphones that sometimes my website crash
the eroror is "a problem repeatedly occurred"
unfortunately it doesnt always happened on the same iphone and on some iphones it doesnt happen at all
i tried all things that written in google like disable suggestions etc etc

does anyone have an idea about it ?
for example i have iphone 15 promax it never happend to my and in another iphone same as mine it does happened
what i did noticed that if its heppeneing it also happend on chrome or google app or safari

thanks to all in advanced

i tried all things that written in google like disable suggestions etc etc